# Trouble trying to install ssh2-python on Mac (OS Catalina)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, macos-catalina

I am trying to download ssh2-python, but continue to get this error. I saw a previous post said to download cmake to fix this issue, but unfortunately it did not help me. Any recommendations on what to do seeing the error below? Thank you!

```
pip3 install ssh2-python

Collecting ssh2-python

  Using cached ssh2-python-0.18.0.post1.tar.gz (1.1 MB)

Installing collected packages: ssh2-python 

    Running setup.py install for ssh2-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-3kzvpatz/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-3kzvpatz/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-record-51uifsty/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/ssh2-python
         cwd: /private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-3kzvpatz/ssh2-python/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    /bin/sh: cmake: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-3kzvpatz/ssh2-python/setup.py", line 36, in <module>
        build_ssh2()
      File "/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-3kzvpatz/ssh2-python/_setup_libssh2.py", line 21, in build_ssh2
        check_call('cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON     -DENABLE_ZLIB_COMPRESSION=ON -DENABLE_CRYPT_NONE=ON     -DENABLE_MAC_NONE=ON -DCRYPTO_BACKEND=OpenSSL' returned non-zero exit status 127.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-3kzvpatz/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-3kzvpatz/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-record-51uifsty/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/ssh2-python Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Can you add the main error text in the question? It makes this question more searchable for future viewers and it also makes it easier to see what error you are talking about.

Comment: @GarriganStafford I just added the text from the Terminal. Please let me know if that helps

Answer (score 3):

You need `cmake` to compile the lib. If you have `homebrew` installed, use the following command to install the `cmake`. Then open a new terminal and try to install the ssh2-python.

`brew install cmake`